# Transfer Function Model

Tags: r

I am a civil engineer not very much used to programming but, somehow managed to understand R programming a bit. I want to use the Transfer Function Model for 2 inputs and 1 output. I am getting some coefficients and intercept. Can anyone help me in understanding these coefficients and how to develop the model further?

### Input:

```
attach(isps_data)
tfm2(Power,Head,Discharge)
library(timeSeries)
# Loading  required package: timeDate
library(MTS)
tfm2(Power,Head,Discharge)

#    Regular ARMA coefficients & s.e.: ar1 coef.arma 
#    0.7148 se.arma 0.0446 Transfer function coefficients & s.e.: intercept X v 
#    -13.22 0.2523 -0.0216 0.012590 se.v 1.08 0.0145 0.0146 0.000121 Sigma-square 
#    & sigma: 0.2446441 0.4946151
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to ask a better question please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: First, this is a broad question. Second, StackOverflow helps with specific coding questions and not model specification or explanation. See other StackExchange sites for this need but please provide data, actual modeling code, and question on whatever platform you use. Good luck!

Comment: Input: attach(isps_data)
> tfm2(Power,Head,Discharge)
> library(timeSeries)
Loading required package: timeDate
> library(MTS)
> tfm2(Power,Head,Discharge)Regular ARMA coefficients & s.e.: 
             ar1
coef.arma 0.7148
se.arma   0.0446
Transfer function coefficients & s.e.: 
     intercept      X                 
v       -13.22 0.2523 -0.0216 0.012590
se.v      1.08 0.0145  0.0146 0.000121
Sigma-square & sigma:  0.2446441 0.4946151

Comment: Hi, you will need to post some reproducible data if you want us to help you. Even with the code you give us we can't help you that much, but like Parfait said, stack is not really the place for model explanation.